# Opening multiple MS Access application with powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access

Good day everyone. I'm new to powershell so I don't know what's wrong with this. I have this script to open multiple MS Access at once as you see in the script and it is save in my local drive. If I run this script in VS Code editor, the script is fine and two application is launch. Now if I run this script using mouse `Right-Click` and `Run with powershell`. At runtime, both application is visible but after the script completed/done, only one application is running and the other is closed.

```
$accessMenu = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
$AccessPath1 = "G:\access1.MDB"
$accessMenu.OpenCurrentDatabase($AccessPath1, $false)
$accessMenu.Visible = $true

$accessLink = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
$AccessPath2 = "G:\access2.accdb"
$accessLink.OpenCurrentDatabase($AccessPath2, $false)
$accessLink.Visible = $true
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance for sharing your idea's.

Comment: I don't know how to code it in PowerShell but I can do it in VBScript, if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you for having an interest in this. Can you show me how?

Comment: Why do you need a script to open 2 databases?

Comment: Actually, there are like a total of 5 application that I need to run just to maximize my productivity.  There are 3 MS Access database and 2 excel files so I would like to automate opening those just by running some script. It kinda annoys me opening them one by one every time I work on some task.

Comment: And there's this database that requires password and It's where I'm stuck right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBScript that will open multiple dbs. It utilizes Windows Shell object. Create a text file and change the extension to vbs. Double click the file to run.

```
Dim objFSO1, objFS02, oShell1, oShell2
Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell1.Run """G:\access1.MDB"""
Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell2.Run """G:\access2.accdb"""
```

The only way I can get multiple databases to open and include a password is in VBA.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim accdbObj1 As Access.Application
Dim accdbObj2 As Access.Application
____________________________________________________________________________
Sub test()
Set accdbObj1 = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accdbObj1.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Owner\June\Forums\demofile.accdb", , "test"
accdbObj1.Application.Visible = True

Set accdbObj2 = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accdbObj2.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Owner\June\DOT\Projects.accdb"
accdbObj2.Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and add another instance of Access.Application named accdbObj3 but it closes the first accdbObj1. Maybe it can't handle 3 instances or what? Any idea?

Comment: It's been a while but I recall having to add an option to pass control to the user, in order for msaccess to stay open. See the examples here: https://www.devhut.net/ms-access-VBA-open-another-database/ with the `.UserControl = True` parameter in the last example. Also btw the option to use a shell command should work too (@Jhunsen Samonte - your ps script looks like it is using automation, rather than simply starting the executable - so that may be the difference).

Comment: For reference, the docs on [OpenCurrentDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.opencurrentdatabase) also make it clear that the app closes when the reference goes out of scope (but they don't give any example of .UserControl - that is not a parameter to the OpenCurrentDatabase method but rather a property set on the application after it is started (I think I always did this right after starting the app, usually - not after opening a database).

Comment: Thank you so much @topsail! This really help me. And yes they mention it in the docs. I just didn't read it all. My fault. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

For future preference:

As per @topsail said, by passing `UserControl = $true` in the instantiated variable of `Access.Application` it prevents the closing of object/application upon script termination/complete.

In powershell:

```
$accessObj = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application -Property @{UserControl = $true}
```

In VBA:

```
Dim accdbObj
Set accdbObj = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accdbObj.OpenCurrentDatabase "G:\path\test.mdb", , "password"
accdbObj.Application.Visible = True
accdbObj.UserControl = True
```